# Get variable name from value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have one `JSON` file and the contents of `JSON` are below. I am reading the JSON file in iOS and according to that I show the data in display.

```
"start": {
            "title": "Welcome",
            "toPoint": "Hello World"
        }
```

What I want to do is that I want to provide dynamic value of

> "title": "Welcome"

from `struct` or `enum` or any `let` constant.

So when i read the data from `JSON` like below I get the value Welcome

```
let title = dict["start"]["title"]
```

Now there will be one constant like below and it should display that text.

```
let Welcome = "This is the actual string to display"
```

Is it possible to do such kind of stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do this.
All you'll need is a Dictionary.

```
var titles: [String: String] = ["Welcome": "This is the actual string to display"]
let title = dict["start"]["title"]
let Welcome = titles[title]
```

If you don't want to use a Dictionary you can use the `KVC` to get the iVar property.
Just make sure your class is inheriting from `NSObject`.

```
let Welcome = "This is the actual string to display"
let title = dict["start"]["title"]
let welcomeString = self.value(forKey: title)
print("Welcome:\(welcomeString)")
```

Alternatively you can move all your Strings in a separate class (not Struct, as KVC is not available for structs):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let title = dict["start"]["title"]
    let welcome = Strings.value(forKey: title)
    print("Welcome:\(welcome)")
}


//MARK: - Strings for our ViewController
fileprivate class Strings:NSObject {
    static let Welcome = "This is the actual string to display"
}

}
```

Comment: I guess there is some misunderstanding. My question is simple to find variable with string value and assign value of that variable to label.

Answer (score 1):

You can't; Variables names are constants in code, you can't set them with a string value :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Analyze your question

i try to think since 10 minutes why you really need this?

i guess your need this to localize something?

then there are many solutions for that.

#### Internationalization and Localization

Apple included already many toys for Internationalization and Localization:

see here: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

or there are many other libs make the i18n live more easy

for example this: https://github.com/Kekiiwaa/Localize

#### Solution with dictionaries

if you don't like the solutions above, the only way to do it can be via a dictionary:

```
var dict = [
    "Welcome" : "Hello Wold",
    "Thanks"  : "Tank you",
    "Hello"   : "Hello"
]

var key = "Welcome"
print(dict[key]!) // -> "Hello Wold"
```

you can nest dictionaries:

```
var dict = [
    "en": [
        "Welcome" : "Hello Wold",
        "Thanks"  : "Tank you",
        "Hello"   : "Hello"
    ],
    "de": [
        "Welcome" : "Guten Tag",
        "Thanks"  : "Danke",
        "Hello"   : "Hallo"
    ]
]

var language = "de"
var key = "Welcome"
print(dict[language]![key]!) --> "Guten Tag"
```

PS: but you should better use the default i18n solutions

#### Reverse engineering

for reverse engineering is the `Mirror` a class to inspect classes and structs and enums

if this is interesting for you see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror

Comment: I am learning swift and iOS and one idea came to mind for applying reverse engineering that lead me to ask a question. And there is nothing like localisation I would give a try as of now.

Comment: for reverse engineering ist Mirror a class to inspect classes and structs and enums - if this is interesting for you ( https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror )